# Is it normal when thread name gets 4 digits name suffix (like RxNewThreadScheduler-1009)?

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpool, rx-java, polling

I make a kind of polling - every 1s I call `read()`, get some value and send via `inform(value)` ([LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) under the hood). The `readSubs.unsubscribe();` is just in case next poll is faster that previous read.

```
public void read(){
    readSubs.unsubscribe();
    readSubs = connection.read()
                    .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Integer value) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "read " + value);
                            inform(value);
                        }
                    });
}

public void inform(Integer value) {
    Log.d(TAG, "informed " + value + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
    broadcaster.newValue(value);  //broadcaster extends LocalBroadcastManager
}
```

I observer on logcat that

```
informed value 70 on thread Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1009,5,main]
```

So far I get thread name up to `RxNewThreadScheduler-1009` and it's growing. My questions:

1. Is it normal when thread name gets 4 digits name suffix?
2. Does it mean there are actually 1009 threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This happens and is an indication you should use `Schedulers.io()` instead.

2) No, it means you had that many threads started (and most likely completed) from the beginning of your application.

Comment: Can you add some more on: why I should use Schedulers.io()?

Comment: io() reuses threads and its index should not grow that large - saving on your OS' handlers in the process.

Comment: Indeed, with Schedulers.io() the thread name is at most RxIoScheduler-2. Where can I find documentation on that behavior of Schedulers.io()?